# Query large dataset with multiple values asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, performance, data-structures, parse-platform

I am using Parse for a iOS application built with Ionic. There is a Class in Parse called Exercises structured like so:

```
{
    "createdAt": "2015-02-19T21:12:01.882Z",
    "tags": [
        "Foam Roller",
        "Extension",
        "Dumbell",
        "Resistance Band",
        "Gym Ball",
        "Olympic Bar"
    ],
    "exerciseDescription": "Sit on a gym ball so that you feel the bony points at the very bottom of your bum in contact with the ball, sit up straight",
    "exerciseID": "2",
    "exerciseName": "Neutral Spine on Gym  Ball - Single Leg and Arm Lift ",
    "images": [
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14
    ],
    "objectId": "pxDBHt7yhs",
    "reps": "12",
    "resistance": "12",
    "sets": "12",
    "updatedAt": "2015-02-19T22:20:45.510Z"
}
```

I use a series of Checkboxes for the user to search this data (some 4000+ rows) for Tags.

The data above constitutes ONE exercise, bearing in mind there is going to be over 4000 scaling to possibly 8 - 10000 how can I best query this data and return the results.

Currently I filter my data on the client side using AngularJS Filters which works really well, however I would like my data and the heavy lifting to be done by Parse.

My question is:
How do I structure my query in order to return the results asynchronously every time a checkbox (tag) is added to the query arguments array? There may be as many as 10 - 15 items in this array.

Would this be viable in the long run bearing in mind the amount of requests to and from the server? Really how many users does the free package support (30 Requests / second)?

=== UPDATE ===

I have implemented this using the following code:

var parseFilterQuery = function(queryActiveFilters) {

```
var TagSearch = Parse.Object.extend("Exercises");
var query = new Parse.Query(TagSearch);
query.containsAll("equipment", queryActiveFilters);
query.find({
  success: function(object) {

    console.log(object);

  },
  error: function(error) {
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: "Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message
      });
  }
});
};
```

In the console this is working really well - I have encountered an error when I increase the number of items in the array >10 however I think I can cope with that. On average the latency for this query is 120 - 400ms.

Currently I am only querying 30 rows how can I estimate this scaling to > 4000 rows and how can I approach the best solution.

Comment: For the "how many users" question, I don't believe Parse has any hard limit on users. The question you need to ask is what are the use patterns of your users. Will they constantly be performing queries, or will they only perform a couple of queries per day when they open your app and start their exercises. (And might you even be caching some results client side etc - although it sounds like you are doing it from a web front-end, rather than iOS/android, so caching may be too cumbersome)

Comment: In terms of your actual question, I would certainly move the query to the server side. You can do queries on array components, so you can setup a query to ensure that "Dumbbell" is contained in the "tags" array. 

You would then setup either a custom function (which yo can call from a REST call), or better still an express.js route, which would return the results of this query. I'll write up a proper answer a little later on.

Comment: Great, helped already, thanks for taking the time ardrian.

Comment: I have found some good ideas about how many users I can handle here https://parse.com/plans/faq